# Need histogram widget for Qt image processing application

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing an application that streams and processes IR camera image data, using Qt for the GUI. The final image processing steps are rescaling to turn the input image (either 16 bit grayscale or double values) into an 8 bit grayscale image based on a specified value range and then application of a color palette to obtain the final 32 bit ARGB image.

Right now I am using two double spin boxes to input the scaling limits but this is clumsy to use and there is no image histogram information. What I would like is a histogram (just a chart displaying the input image's pixel value distribution) combined with two slider handles that the user can drag around to adjust the rescaling limits. The handles should probably be just two lines intersecting the histogram chart. Ideally the background of the whole thing would also show the color palette used for display, though I could live without it.

I've created some custom Qt widgets before but have so far only combined existing classes into some layouts and connected some signals and slots. From what I've read so far I think I'd probably have to somehow combine a QChart with a variation of a QSlider with two handles instead of one, or actually completely re-write a widget from scratch, including its paint method. Problem is, I have no clue how to approach this as I'm still relatively new to Qt. Any of you have some tips to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just to give an update, I ended up using QML to create a new widget (the QWidget system was too rigid). The suggested options did not quite offer what I had in mind. However, QML ended up being too slow with the histogram calculations. I would have attempted to re-locate those calculations into C++ code but then my company ended up ditching Qt altogether because of licensing issues so I stopped pursuing this.

Answer (score 1):

[Qwt](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/) - Qt Widgets for Technical Applications

The Qwt library contains GUI Components and utility classes which are primarily useful for programs with a technical background. Beside a framework for 2D plots it provides scales, sliders, dials, compasses, thermometers, wheels and knobs to control or display values, arrays, or ranges of type double.

[image]

It provides

- Curve Plots
- Spectrogram, Contour Plot
- Bar Charts, Histograms
- Dials, Compasses, Knobs, Wheels, Sliders, Thermos

Answer (score 0):

You could use [QCustomplot](https://www.qcustomplot.com).
You can then create a histogram using an object of the class **"QCPBars"**.